# How to automatically include the source in swift-log messages?

Tags: swift

I'm using swift-log. I noticed that the Logger class includes some extra info when creating the log

```
debug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> Logger.Message,
                      metadata: @autoclosure () -> Logger.Metadata? = nil,
                      source: @autoclosure () -> String? = nil,
                      file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: UInt = #line)
```

I can easily include the source name in the log String myself `"(Self.self) - Something to log" but I was hoping to avoid this.

Is there a way to get the log message to include the `source` or `file` or `line` automatically?

When I log with this in an XCTestCase

```swift
func testLogging() {
    Logger.default.debug("Something to log")
}
```

I see this output:
`2021-02-26T08:42:10-0800 debug com.apple.dt.xctest.tool : Something to log`

I was hoping to see the test class name, function and line number.

Comment: The file, line, and function in which the message is logged *is* included automatically.

Comment: Also, be more specific about what you mean by the "source" of the message.

Comment: Sorry, I added my log statement and the output.

Comment: You need to implement your own logging backend. See https://github.com/apple/swift-log#on-the-implementation-of-a-logging-backend-a-loghandler

Comment: I see thanks. You mentioned that it could be done automatically. Is there something I could change to allow it to happen automatically?

Comment: The default values for the `file`, `function`, and `line` parameters are `#file`, `#function`, and `#line`, respectively. These special literals evaluate to the file, function, and line in which they appear. In order to control the output of the log message, you must create a type that conforms to the `LogHandler` protocol and install it as the global logging backend by calling `LoggingSystem.bootstrap`. Then, in the `log(level:message:metadata:file:function:line:)` method of your log handler, you can choose how to format the output.

Comment: @PeterSchorn Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Logger supports metadata. I added this helper function to help add the test name:

```swift
extension Logger {

    public mutating func setTestName(_ testName: String) {
        //-[TestClass testName]
        let parts = testName.replacingOccurrences(of: "-[", with: "")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
            .components(separatedBy: " ")
        guard let testClass = parts.first,
              let testName = parts.last,
              testClass != testName,
              NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") != nil
        else { return }
        self[metadataKey: "test"] = "\(testClass).\(testName)"
    }

    // I also use the default Logger that I use for logging
    public static var `default` = Logger.init(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "DefaultLogger")
}
```

Then in my tests, I simply call this in the setup:

```swift
override func setUp() {
   Logger.default.setTestName(self.name)
}
```

My logs went from this:
`2021-02-28T08:27:53-0800 debug com.apple.dt.xctest.tool : !!! Logging debug details`

Into this
`2021-02-28T08:29:05-0800 debug com.apple.dt.xctest.tool : test=LogKitTests.testExample !!! Logging debug details`